# How can Instagram cause wakelocks when disabled?

Tags: disable-app, wakelock, instagram

Can somebody explain me the logic behind how Instagram can still be the top app in my [wakelook detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector.noroot) app even when it is disabled with [Package disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kunkunsoft.packagedisabler)??:O

Comment: I assume there's some other app calling to it – which is still possible even when disabled (intents can be addressed directly; the app then acts like a "library" and offers the addressed functionality). I'd try checking with logcat whether there's an indicator on who calls it, see our [logging tag-wiki](/tags/logging/info).

Comment: Alright nice! I looked into the "logcat" thing and found a way to do it just using ADB. Basically: ADB shell: logcat. 

Now... The logcat outputs a ****load of text, is there any good ways or tools to filter it? Kind of to spot wakelocks and such? 
I guess ctrl+f would be good, but anything better?

Comment: On Linux, I just pipe things to `grep` (eg. `adb logcat -v time | grep -i instagram`). Be welcome to check with my list of [ADB helpers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947) to run on your PC. If you're on Windows, DroidExplorer might be a good choice. Also note the specific logcat helpers there.

Comment: I would imagine what describe for linux, would almost be the same as ctrl+f in a word document on windows for me :) 

And thanks for the link, but I really do no know much about coding, and many of the tools looks quite complicated :O